# how do I link my YUI datatable so it is resized when the YUI layout panel it is in is resized

Tags: resize, yui, yui-datatable

I'm developing a fairly simple database fed web app, that really just displays the contents of a DB in a grid control. 
I have a YUI datatable control which displays the data in a grid, and it resides inside a YUI layout control which splits my screen into 4 panels. The datable is sized to fit entirely into one panel of the yui layout control.
Everything works well, except one thing.  When the user resizes one of the panels, I would like that panel to resize the datable that is displayed within that panel. I have looked at the YUI examples.  But all of them refer to the yui resize control.  Its not clear to me how that control works, or if I need to instantiate, or if the yui layoutpanel inherits its properties... mostly its not clear how I can resize my table inside the panel.
Any ideas?  I'm using 2.7.0

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
.yui-dt-scrollable table {
    width: 100%;
}
```